# BroadcastReceiver fires only once

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I have activity where I have EditText for user to enter certain data. After user writes some text and clicks button, he is waiting for a response from BroadcastReceiver. The problem is that everything works for the first time and user receive response but if user doesn't exit activity and clicks the button again, BroadcastReceiver is not firing anymore. If user closes activity and opens it again, BroadcastReceiver is again working but only for the first time.

This is a little bit confusing. Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent in) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {

            case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                mStatus = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(FLAG));

}
```

When user clicks button:

```
Intent in = new Intent(FLAG);
PendingIntent pIn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, in, 0);
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("123456789", null, "text", pIn, null);

while(!mStatus){
}

mStatus = false;
```

Unregister receiver:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

What do you think? Why it works only when activity is started and button is clicked for the first time?

Comment: Do you mean the user exit the activity, come back and click the button again?

Comment: @CChi, that works. If user exists activity and comes back, it works. The problem is if user stays in activity and wants to click the button for example 6 times, only first time when he clicked it will work. Other five times it wont do anything.

Comment: Do _not_ use an infinite loop on the main thread, even with the `sleep()` someone suggested. You don't need to constantly check the variable's status. Simply start whatever code was "waiting" from `onReceive()` when it gets the broadcast.

Comment: @MikeM., But I want to wait for confirmation that the message is sent before I send another message or do something else. My plan is to upgrade this to send multiple messages to multiple users and I would like to know when the message is sent so I can continue with other messages. How can I accomplish that if I can't like this?

Comment: Just like I said. Send one message; when `onReceive()` fires, check the status and send the next one; when `onReceive()` fires again, check the status and send the next one again;...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Explanation: you should manage the receiver either in `onCreate()` / `onDestroy()` or `onResume()` / `onPause()` (corresponding lifecycle events).

**Edit**: make this change also (second line sets `flag` argument):

```
Intent in = new Intent(FLAG);
PendingIntent pIn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("123456789", null, "text", pIn, null);
```

Not sure if this will fix it because I don't know what the 0 would mean that you were using for the flag value. `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` seems correct though.

**Edit 2**:

```
while(!mStatus){
}
```

You should never do that!

Comment: It's the same. I think that shouldn't be a problem because onPause() or onDestroy() is not called at all because user is staying in activity and clicking the button.

Comment: Edited my answer; By the way, the receiver just sets a boolean to true. Exactly how do you know whether or not it runs?

Comment: I have a boolean flag which is set when `onReceive()` fires and I've put loggers everywhere. First time all loggers log the action and flag is set to true. Other times no logging at all and flag is not set.

Comment: There is really nothing much more related to this. I have that boolean variable which I am checking in infinite `while` loop when user clicks the button. Probably is something wrong with PendingIntent because it's already set with the same value. What do you think?

Comment: Post the infinite while loop :)

Comment: Posted. Something is probably wrong with PendingIntent in `sendTextMessage`. Each time when user clicks the button the same PendingIntent is passed to that method.